# Как прервать выполнение условия if в функции?

Tags: javascript

При вводе в prompt пустой строки или букв выдается окно 'Было введено не число, попробуйте еще раз' и должно снова всплыть окно с полем ввода, но всплывает 'Родители разрешили?' . Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе пустой строки или букв, выводилось 'Было введено не число, попробуйте еще раз' и снова был возврат в поле ввода? То есть пока пользователь не введет возраст, будет возврат к полю ввода. Я думал может это как-то можно сделать через цикл и break и continue, но так и не понял как.

```js
let age = prompt('Сколько вам лет?', '');

function checkAge(age) {
  if (isNaN(age) || age === '') alert('Было введено не число, попробуйте еще раз');
  if (age > 18) return true;
  else return confirm('А родители разрешили?');
}

if (checkAge(age)) {
  alert('Доступ получен');
} else {
  alert('Доступ закрыт');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Оборачиваем ваши вопросы в цикл while. Повторяем до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет цифры или не закроет страницу

```js
  let age = '';

  let ask = true;

  function checkAge(age) {
    if (!age) return false; // Если нажмут отмену придет null, при проверке на isNaN будет true
    if (isNaN(age) || age === '') {
      alert('Было введено не число, попробуйте еще раз');
      return false;
    }
    ask = false
    if (parseInt(age) > 18) return true;
    else return confirm('А родители разрешили?');
  }

  while (ask) {
    age = prompt('Сколько вам лет?', '');
    if (checkAge(age)) {
      alert('Доступ получен');
    } else {
      alert('Доступ закрыт');
    }
  }
```

Более правильнее было бы разнести ваши вопросы для пользователя

```js
  let age = '';

  let ask = true;

  function checkAge(age) {
    if (!age) return false;
    if (isNaN(age)) {
      alert('Было введено не число, попробуйте еще раз');
      return false;
    }
    return true
  }

  while (ask) {
    age = prompt('Сколько вам лет?', '').trim();
    ask = !checkAge(age);
  }

  if (Number(age) < 18 ? confirm('А родители разрешили?') : true) {
    alert('Доступ получен');
  } else {
    alert('Доступ закрыт');
  }
```