# Как сделать проверку через бесконечный цикл?

Tags: javascript

```js
function checkAge() {
  let age = prompt('Сколько вам лет?', '');
  while(isNaN(age) || age === '') {
    alert('Было введено не число, попробуйте еще раз');
    age = prompt('Сколько вам лет?', '');
  }
  if (age > 18) return true;
  else return confirm('А родители разрешили?');
}

if (checkAge()) {
  alert('Доступ получен');
} else {
  alert('Доступ закрыт');
}
```

Comment: Я же вам уже отвечал [проверка ввода данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1470250/1470258#1470258) - чем  вам ответ не подходит?

Comment: длинный код и мудреный

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прервать выполнение условия if в функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1470250/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-if-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkAge() {
    let age;
    while (!age || isNaN(age)) {
        age = prompt('Сколько вам лет?', '');
        if (age >= 18) {
            alert('Доступ получен');
        }
        else if (age && age < 18) {
            if (confirm('А родители разрешили?')) {
                alert('Доступ получен');
            } else {
                alert('Доступ закрыт');
            }
        }
    }
}

checkAge()
```