# Nan суммируется после ввода не числа, и не могу продолжить подсчет суммы

Tags: javascript, prompt

Написал программу для подсчета суммы при взаимодействии с пользователем через prompt. При вводе цифр все про[image: введите сюда описание изображения]ходит хорошо, считает сумму, при нажатии на cancel выходило.Решил добавить проверку на не число, как только ввожу не число выскакивает Nan, что хорошо, но проблема в том что когда ввожу число после этого оно суммирует Nan и ничего нельзя сделать.

И еще может кто знает: консоль глючит когда делаешь clear и некорректно отображает изменение . спасает только закрытие liveServera, потом комментирование кода, потом открытие сервера и раскомментирование кода.

```js
let input;
let total = 0;
let message = `Общая сумма чисел равна ${total}`;
for (let i = 0; i !== null; i += 1) {
  input = prompt('Введите число:');
  input = Number(input);

  if (input === null) {
    alert(`Общая сумма чисел равна ${total}`);
    break;
  } else if (input === Number.isNaN(input)) {
    continue;
  } else {
    total += input;
    console.log(`Общая сумма чисел  ${total} `);
  }
}
```

Comment: У вас проверка на NaN не работает. Посмотрите про [преобразование чисел и проверку на NaN](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461372/1461463#1461463). isNaN вернет true или false, а вы сравниваете с вашим input. А вот тут можно посмотреть, как организовать проверку на то, что [введено не число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1470250/1470258#1470258)

Comment: да,спасибо.Ваш ответ на ссылку "введено не число" мне помог.переделал под себя и помогло:  else if (isNaN(input) || input === '') {
    alert('Было введено не число, попробуйте еще раз');
    continue;

Comment: `input === Number.isNaN(input)` — расскажите что делает эта строка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> input = Number(input);
> ```

Удалить.

> ```
> } else if (input === Number.isNaN(input)) {
> ```

```
} else if (isNaN(input)) {
```

> ```
> total += input;
> ```

```
total += +input;
```

Comment: спасибо. Ваш ответ сработал, даже без последней строки все считается и останавливается когда не число. С последней строчкой тоже работает

Comment: @АлексейТкаченко, не может без последней строчки правильно работать. А если проблема решена, надо принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: сумму он считает итак хорошо. ``let input;
let total = 0;
let message = `Общая сумма чисел равна ${total}`;
for (let i = 0; i !== null; i += 1) {
  input = prompt('Введите число:');

  if (input === null) {
    alert(`Общая сумма чисел равна ${total}`);
    break;
  } else if (isNaN(input)) {
    alert('Было введено не число, попробуйте еще раз');
  } else if (input !== null) {
    input = Number(input);
    total += input;
    console.log(`Общая сумма чисел  ${total} `);
  }
}`` немного подправил код, так как cancel не работал